# A Probability Problem about the $Trypanosoma$ parasite

Tags: probability

Considering the distribution of *Trypanosoma* (parasite) lengths shown below, suppose we take a **sample of two** Tryoanosomes. What is the *probability* that:

a) **both** Trypanosomes will be shorter than 20um?

b) **the first** Trypanosome will be **shorter than 20um** and the **second** will be **longer than 25um?**

c) **exactly one** of the Trypanosomes will be **shorter than 20um** and **one** will be **longer than 25um**?

[image]

I have no idea were to start. Even though it looks like an easy solution, this question is kind of confusing, especially the B and C part. Could someone please help me to get on the right track? Thank you for your help guys!

Comment: The distribution is currently not shown below.

Comment: Distribution is shown in the density curve I have uploaded. It's the exact curve that was given to solve the problem. I have no idea how to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three questions can be solved in a pretty similar fashion.  The key to answering them is using the rule that, if $A$ and $B$ are independent events, then $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ — in other words, multiply the probabilities of each event.  So for example, the probability of selecting a parasite shorter than 20 micrometers is $0.01 + 0.34 = 0.35$.  The probability of selecting two such parasites, then, is $(0.35)(0.35) = 0.1225$.

There is a twist in the final question.  The second question dictates what order you select the parasites in.  But the third question states simply that you pick two parasites.  Therefore, you could pick the shorter parasite followed by the longer one or the longer one followed by the shorter one.  If $A$ is the first event and $B$ the second, you're seeking $P(A\cup B)$.  If $P(A\cap B) = 0$ — which is the case here; it's impossible to pick both the shorter parasite *and* the longer one first — then $P(A\cap B) = P(A) + P(B)$.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, I think it does. So for part B, since the first is shorter than 20um and the second longer than 25um- we have to multiply them: (0.01+0.34) x (0.21+0.03)= 0.084 ; and then for part C, since it states that one is shorter than 20um and one is longer than 25um, we need to add, so: 0.35 + 0.24 = 0.59, does it look correct?

Comment: Got it! For part C, since it's P(A) + P(B), it's (0.35 x 0.24) + (0.24 x 0.35) = 0.168 ; it makes sense now! Seriously, you're a lifesaver! Thank you so much!

Comment: @juknee Your solutions look good.  And good catch with C:  We can give an event a simple name like $A$, but we can make it stand for something as complicated as we want; note that the first half of part C encompassed all of your answer to part B.